# Do class properties count as attributes or methods on a class diagram?

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram

Example here:

```
Public Class myclass
 Private one As Integer
 Public Property myproperty() As myproperty
    Get
        Return one
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As myproperty)
        one= value
    End Set
 End Property
End Class
```

I understand myclass would be the class, and one would be an attribute, but what about myproperty?

Answer (score 1):

I would say 'one' is just an implementation detail and should not appear in UML. You would simply have a UML Class 'myclass' with a UML Property (what you named attribute) 'myproperty'.